# Conservation of angular momentum in particles reactions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws

In particles or nuclear reactions the square modulus of total angular momentum (the sum of spin and orbital angular momentum) is conserved.

When calculating the density of states to compute cross section for reactions, the spatial density of states is multiplied by the spins multiplicity $(2s_a+1)(2s_b+1)$ as the particles could come out of the reactions in any spins combination, not conserving the square modulus of total angulat momentum in some states and the third component in many states.
Should the third component of total angular momentum be also conserved?
Is it true that there no restriction on the spins of the resulting particles?

The angular momentum conservation could be restored by the orbital angular momentum component. But how is it guaranteed that there is enough energy for the system to be in the needed orbital angular momentum state?

Why is this? It look strange to me.

Comment: The total angular momentum is conserved, with consequences on the spin/chirality of the interactions. It is just that in the standard treatments, we are caring much more about the linear momenta, and the angular momenta are thus not the conserved quantum numbers. It is then difficult to see how they are conserved, but we are not attempting to violate this conservation.